# WPF datagrid binding too slow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

In my WPF application i generate datagrid with dynamic number of columns.
Part of the code:

```
for (var i = datetime; i < datetime.AddDays(1); i+= TimeSpan.FromHours(1)){
    var column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    column.Header = (i+1).ToString();
    column.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(
            new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(
                @"<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'><TextBlock Text='{Binding Values[" + i + @"]." + propName + @"}'/></DataTemplate>"
            ))); 
    column.CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(
            new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(
                @"<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'><TextBox Text='{Binding Values[" + i + @"]." + propName + @", Mode=TwoWay}'/></DataTemplate>"
            ))); 
    dataGrid1.Columns.Add(column);
}
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data;

<DataGrid EnableColumnVirtualization="true" EnableRowVirtualization="true" Name="dataGrid1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                   Height="120" Width="Auto" />
```

When my table contains 25 columns and 10 rows it's rendered too slowly(1 sec).
How can i improve performance of data binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same data template instance for all your columns.

Just move the `XamlReader.Load()` calls outside of the loop and use the same instances for all your columns:

```cs
var cellTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(...);
var cellEditTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(...);
for(...)
{
   //..
   column.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;
   column.CellEditingTemplate = cellEditTemplate;
   //...
}
```